# Is it possible to use h.264 4:4:4 RDP on Windows 8.1 Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

I've a Windows 8.1 machine that needs to RDP to a Windows 10 machine.

Is there some 3rd party software that supports the new [4:4:4 mode in RDP 10](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/01/11/remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-10-avch-264-improvements-in-windows-10-and-windows-server-2016-technical-preview/) or can you enable it in MSTSC 8.1?

Comment: Are you looking for 3rd party product that does AVC 4:4:4 or are you looking to see if you can turn it on in MSTSC / RDP?

Comment: Anything that makes it work, 3rd party or patch.

Comment: AVC 4:4:4 is not available on Windows 8.1, but you can maybe look at Citrix (maybe they have something)?